# A simple secenario to implement JavaScript ASP.NET C#, question rephrased

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I had asked this question before, but I got no correct answer.

So, this is a simple thing:

```
textbox.text='user typing';
```

Button: store the value to a variable and a database.

Very simple, nothing to it.
But there should be no post back, that is the page must not load again.

Try Ajax? I tried it, but it is not working.

I lost a lot of time trying to implement this using JavaScript Ajax and read many many posts.

But for some reason I cannot implement the functionality correctly.

Comment: If you provide some code showing what you've already tried, you'll probably have more luck getting an answer. If possible, consider showing the relevant html, your ajax call, and whatever resource your ajax method calls (for example, the web method, if you're calling a web method). If you've never done this before, I highly recommend visiting Encosia, particularly the article [Using jQuery to directly call ASP.NET AJAX page methods](http://encosia.com/2008/05/29/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/).

Comment: Also perhaps add some details on in what way it does not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   var xmlHttp; 
   var is_ie = (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE') >= 0) ? 1 : 0; 
    var is_ie5 = (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE 5.5")!=-1) ? 1 : 0; 
    var is_opera = ((navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Opera6")!=-1)||(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Opera/6")!=-1)) ? 1 : 0; 
    //netscape, safari, mozilla behave the same??? 
    var is_netscape = (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Netscape') >= 0) ? 1 : 0; 

    function btnClick(){ 
        if (strReportURL.length > 0)
        { 

            //Create the xmlHttp object to use in the request 
            //stateChangeHandler will fire when the state has changed, i.e. data is received back 
            // This is non-blocking (asynchronous) 
            xmlHttp = GetXmlHttpObject(handler); 
            //Send the xmlHttp get to the specified url 
            xmlHttp_Get(xmlHttp, "AjaxHanlder.aspx?Data="+txtData.Text,handler); 

        } 

    } 

    //stateChangeHandler will fire when the state has changed, i.e. data is received back 
    // This is non-blocking (asynchronous) 
    function handler() 
    { 
        //readyState of 4 or 'complete' represents that data has been returned 
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 || xmlHttp.readyState == 'complete')
        { 
            //Gather the results from the callback 
            var result = xmlHttp.responseText; 

            //Populate the innerHTML of the div with the results 
            document.getElementById('lblResult').innerHTML = result;        
        } 
    } 


    // XMLHttp send GET request 
    function xmlHttp_Get(xmlhttp, url,handler) { 
        xmlhttp.open('GET', url, true); 
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = handler; 
        xmlhttp.send(null); 
    } 

    function GetXmlHttpObject(handler) { 
        var objXmlHttp = null;    //Holds the local xmlHTTP object instance 

        //Depending on the browser, try to create the xmlHttp object 
        if (is_ie){ 
            //The object to create depends on version of IE 
            //If it isn't ie5, then default to the Msxml2.XMLHTTP object 
            var strObjName = (is_ie5) ? 'Microsoft.XMLHTTP' : 'Msxml2.XMLHTTP'; 

            //Attempt to create the object 
            try{ 
            if(!objXmlHttp)
                objXmlHttp = new ActiveXObject(strObjName); 
                //objXmlHttp.onreadystatechange = handler; 
            } 
            catch(e){ 
            //Object creation errored 
                alert('IE detected, but object could not be created. Verify that active scripting and activeX controls are enabled'); 
                return; 
            } 
        } 
        else if (is_opera){ 
            //Opera has some issues with xmlHttp object functionality 
            alert('Opera detected. The page may not behave as expected.'); 
            return; 
        } 
        else{ 
            // Mozilla | Netscape | Safari 
            objXmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
            objXmlHttp.onload = handler; 
            objXmlHttp.onerror = handler; 
        } 

        //Return the instantiated object 
        return objXmlHttp; 
    } 


///AJAX HANDLER PAGE

public class AjaxHandler : System.Web.UI.Page
    {


private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {

      if(Request.QueryString["Data"]!=null)
      {

            StoreYourData(Request.QueryString);
      }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should make an `IHttpHandler`.